# Performing a function on a specific button when clicked using jquery

Tags: jquery, this

I have multiple buttons on my site with a class of details.

What I want is to target just that button that is clicked on to perform my jquery fadeIn function. The way it's set up now when you click on the details button the jquery fadeIn function gets applied to all the buttons with the same class.

I tried using $(this), but it still doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you :)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".details").click(function() {
        $(".popup", $(this)).fadeIn(2000);              
    });     
});  
</script>
```

Sorry for not adding the html. Basically what happens is when the details button is clicked the info in the popup box will appear.

```
<h1>
    We look good together<span class="location">1223 w. street ave</span>
    <span class="details"><a href="#">Details</a></span>
</h1>

<div class="popup">
    <ul>
        <li>852</li><!--Square Foot goes here-->
        <li>2</li><!--Bedrooms goes here-->
        <li>1</li><!--Bathrooms goes here-->
        <li>$134,900</li><!--Price goes here-->                 
    </ul>               
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried `$(this).fadeIn(2000);` ?

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?  `$(".popup", $(this))` is the same as `$(this).find('.popup')`.

Comment: Please post here your HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `.popup` is not in the same parent as `.details`?  If so, you need to use `.parents` and `.next` to find the popup after your details element:

```
$(".details").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('h1').next('.popup').fadeIn(2000);              
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6CHX/

Comment: Thank you so much Jeff B this worked! I've been racking my brain all day : )

Comment: No problem... Now accept some answers or no one will want to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: I know I apologize for that. When I discovered stackoverflow I had no idea how it worked. I'm learning : )

Comment: No need to apologize, that's how we all start.  We are just informing you how the system works.  To accept an answer, btw, you click the check mark under the vote count.  Up-voting is good, but as the question asker, you are the only one who can click the check mark to say that the answer is the one you found most helpful.

Comment: Hey Jeff, Thanks for pointing that out, I just clicked the check mark : )

Comment: My answer was sooner and provided the `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` I guess when it's a matter of minutes or even seconds you can't win'em all. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a repeated pattern:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".details").click(function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // remove if the anchor rel is actually meant to trigger
        thePopup = $(this).closest('h1').next('.popup'); // traverse to the proper popup
        thePopup.fadeIn(2000);              
    });     
});
```

If it's not a repeated pattern, you can save a headache by binding click to the one details button that pops up the one related popup, using different classes or IDs as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question right, this may help,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".details").click(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(2000);              
    });     
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Jashwant, Sorry for the vagueness, I just posted more details about how it's supposed to work along with some html. thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You could try:

```
$(".details").click(function(event) {
    $(".popup", $(this)).fadeIn(2000);
    event.stopPropagation()              
});
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

This is not an ideal solution however. Best solution would be to be more specific on the click selector.

Comment: event it's not even defined in the context of his function

Comment: "stop the event from being propagated to the other elements with that class".  That's not what `stopPropagation` does. http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: `stopPropagation` still isn't the right tool here.  This is what `stopPropagation` is used for => http://jsfiddle.net/vdaG3/1/

Comment: @Rocket it works if you only want to manipulate the element clicked doesn't it? http://jsfiddle.net/vdaG3/7/